# How to remove preceding zeros in a string element from a Python list

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
my_list = ['0300', '0023', '0005', '000030']
```

I want to remove the preceding zeroes in each string element from the list. So I want strip the 0s from the left side of the string.

Output would be like this:

```
my_list = ['300', '23', '5', '30']
```

I've tried this:

```
for x in my_list:
    x = re.sub(r'^0+', "", x) 
    print my_list
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Please help!

Comment: `l = [a.lstrip("0") for a in l]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`str.lstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) like this

```
print [item.lstrip('0') for item in l]
# ['300', '23', '5', '30']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
list = [str(int(el)) for el in list]
```

Edit: pick the other answer, I'd prefer that one too :-)

Comment: No it won't, I just tested it. However, the other solution _is_ the better one :P. What you're thinking of is octal literals. Examples: int('0300') gives 300, int(0300) gives 192, int(0x300) gives 768. The quote marks make all the difference.